# Can I check whether a variable has deterministic value by C++ API

Tags: c++, z3

I noticed that Z3 can do allsmt from some paper. In my project, I have to search for deterministic variables in a SMT formula. By deterministic I mean the variable can only take one int value to make the formula satisfiable. Is there a c++/c API function which can do this task?

The best I can do so far is to call the solver.check() function many times for the negation of each variable I am interested in. Is there a faster way to do this by using the API?

Basically, I want to do allsmt and predicate abstraction/projection.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specialized API for checking if all models of a given variable have to agree on the same value. You can implement more or less efficient algorithms on top of Z3 to solve this question.
Here is a possible algorithm:

1. Get a model M from Z3.
2. For the variables you are interested in assert: Not (And([(M.eval(x) == x) for x in Vars]))
3. Recheck satisfiability. If the new state is unsatisfiable, then the remaining variales in Vars must have the same value. Otherwise, remove variables from Vars that evaluate to a new value different from the old M.eval(x), and repeat (2) until Vars is either empty or the context is unsatisfiable.